# How to run git commands on remote without having local repo

Tags: git, tags, branch, export

I have a script called 'git-export' which helps me to export a remote repository. It is run like that:

```
git-export http://host.com/git-repo <-t tag or -b branch or -c commit> /local/dir
```

Before it was used to export local repository and I used these commands:

to get commit from branch:

```
git branch -v --no-abbrev|awk '($1=="'$BRANCH'") || ($1 == "*" && $2 == "'$BRANCH'"){if($1 == "*"){print $3;}else{print $2;}}'
```

or

```
git rev-parse -q --verify $BRANCH^{commit}
```

to get commit by tag:

```
git rev-parse -q --verify $TAG^{commit}
```

also I have scripts to list tags, versions (tags, starting with v), I use git branch -v to show branches....

Question is: How can I do these things on remote repository without having local. Is there some general way to query remote. For example: `git --remote=http://host.com/repo branch -v` or `git --remote=http://host.com/repo log`

Resion: If I want to install software on remote host I just want to

1. list versions, branches, etc
2. export specific version/branch/commit and show SHA1 of the commit regardless which one of these I export (by export I mean `git archive --remote=<repo>|tar x`)

edit:

I don't want to actionalyl run the commands on remote. I want to use the remote repository with local commands and display it formatted.

Answer (score 35):

You're looking for [`git ls-remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html). For example:

```
$ git ls-remote git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
4d8b32a2e1758236c4c1b714f179892e3bce982c    HEAD
f75a94048af9e423a3d8cba694531d0d08bd82b4    refs/heads/html
810cae53e0f622d6804f063c04a83dbc3a11b7ca    refs/heads/maint
70b5eebd65f2d47fd69073aed1d3da0f1fd7a017    refs/heads/man
4d8b32a2e1758236c4c1b714f179892e3bce982c    refs/heads/master
b9f1b13437fd0b8b1857ffbdebb9e1adc50481f0    refs/heads/next
83a9d3226b19a683a9a783bde0784c2caf19e9a1    refs/heads/pu
2309986900ed1a5744b3a81c507943593000ce32    refs/heads/todo
d5aef6e4d58cfe1549adef5b436f3ace984e8c86    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0
3d654be48f65545c4d3e35f5d3bbed5489820930    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0^{}
33682a5e98adfd8ba4ce0e21363c443bd273eb77    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.1
729ffa50f75a025935623bfc58d0932c65f7de2f    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.1^{}
...
(git.git has a lot of tags!)
```

You can limit yourself to branches with the `--heads` option or tags with the `--tags` option, or specify a pattern to select refs, for example to see only the git version tags from git.git, `git ls-remote <url> refs/tags/v*`. Or you might already know exactly what ref you want: `git ls-remote <url> HEAD`.

You can't run arbitrary commands on arbitrary remotes, though. The transfer protocols don't support that - they're designed to support listing refs and transferring objects (via packs). In particular, you won't be able to do anything analogous to `rev-list`. You'll be limited to getting SHA1s for commits pointed to by refs.

Comment: that looks pretty useful and I think it'll do the job, but is there a command that accepts --format argument? One of the problems with this format: ^{} means that this is the commit that the tag points to. However if the tag is lightweight then the commit sha1 will be without ^{}. I want to get the sha1 of the commit when listing tags, regardless of the type of the tag. I used `for-each-ref` with --format to do that. see `man git-for-each-ref`

Comment: @NickSoft: Yeah, I know what you mean, but I think you'll probably have to do it yourself. If you can count on all tags being annotated (which is probably good practice anyway), you can do `git ls-remote <url> refs/tags/*^{}`, but otherwise I think you'll have to read the list and do a little post-processing. (Of course, note that you can use the annotated tag's SHA1 for `git archive` anyway, so you could also just strip out all of the pointed-to commits with a `grep -v '\^{}$'` and be done with it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl for checking if the specific url exists or not
for example
when i try to hit angularjs existing url

```
$ curl -I https://github.com/angular/angularjs.org/tree/master/src
**HTTP/1.1 200 OK**
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Mon, 11 Aug 2014 15:22:40 GMT
```

When I hit on a wrong URL

```
$ curl -I https://github.com/angular/angularjs.org/tree/master/abcd
**HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found**
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Mon, 11 Aug 2014 15:24:06 GMT
```

Hope this helps