# Search remote repository for file names/contents

Tags: git

Is it possible to search a remote repository for a file without having cloned it locally? Given for example [the `clone` URL for this project](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js), could I search the master branch for a file with a particular name? A file that contains a certain string?

[`git-ls-remote`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687680/1252748) seems like it is [kind of close to what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687680/1252748), but combining it with [`git-ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) or [`git-grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) doesn't work ([SO post showing how to use these for the same task on a local instance of a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5681657/1252748))

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js.git ls-files '*/mixin.js'
```

just returns to the command prompt without printing any output at all, errors or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to search a remote repository for a file without having cloned it locally?

The short answer currently is "No".

Whilst `ls-remote` might look promising it only lists *references*, not files.

You also can't combine git commands in the way that you are attempting (unless the commands involved specifically support such combinations).

In addition to only working on refs, the reason the attempt to combine `ls-remote` with `ls-files` returns nothing is that the `ls-files` entry on the command line is interpreted by the `ls-remote` command as limiting output to only return refs that match "ls-files" (or "*/mixin.js").

There are none, so you get no output.

If you are concerned about the size of the repository you need to `clone` in order to do your searches locally and are only interested in the latest revision of the repo and are not concerned with files that may have existed in the history but are no longer present etc, you can of course limit `clone` to the most current revision, to avoid cloning the complete repo and history, using the `--depth` param e.g.:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js.git
```

This doesn't avoid having to clone, but it does reduce the amount of work/time involved in doing so.